# How can I a select certain range of objects from an array

Tags: javascript

Let say from the example I want to select the last three objects in the array, how should I write my code so that it outputs only the last three objects? These are the codes I have trying to use to get the but they do not yield the expected output, how should write my code to achieve my expected output.

#### Codes Tired

```
monthlyInfo[3,5]
```

```
monthlyInfo[3][5]
```

#### Example

```
var monthyInfo =[{Date: "Jan 2020 ( NaN )", Balance: 747798, Mortgage: 2827, Principal: 2202, Interest: 625, …}
{Date: "Feb 2020 ( NaN )", Balance: 745594, Mortgage: 2827, Principal: 2204, Interest: 623, …}
{Date: "Mar 2020 ( NaN )", Balance: 743388, Mortgage: 2827, Principal: 2206, Interest: 621, …}
{Date: "Apr 2020 ( NaN )", Balance: 741181, Mortgage: 2827, Principal: 2208, Interest: 619, …}
{Date: "May 2020 ( NaN )", Balance: 738972, Mortgage: 2827, Principal: 2209, Interest: 618, …}
{Date: "Jun 2020 ( NaN )", Balance: 736760, Mortgage: 2827, Principal: 2211, Interest: 616, …}]
```

#### Expected Output

```
[{Date: "Apr 2020 ( NaN )", Balance: 741181, Mortgage: 2827, Principal: 2208, Interest: 619, …}
{Date: "May 2020 ( NaN )", Balance: 738972, Mortgage: 2827, Principal: 2209, Interest: 618, …}
{Date: "Jun 2020 ( NaN )", Balance: 736760, Mortgage: 2827, Principal: 2211, Interest: 616, …}]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can use [Array.slice](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/slice) for this purpose, e.g.:

```js
var monthyInfo =[{Date: "Jan 2020 ( NaN )", Balance: 747798, Mortgage: 2827, Principal: 2202, Interest: 625},
{Date: "Feb 2020 ( NaN )", Balance: 745594, Mortgage: 2827, Principal: 2204, Interest: 623},
{Date: "Mar 2020 ( NaN )", Balance: 743388, Mortgage: 2827, Principal: 2206, Interest: 621},
{Date: "Apr 2020 ( NaN )", Balance: 741181, Mortgage: 2827, Principal: 2208, Interest: 619},
{Date: "May 2020 ( NaN )", Balance: 738972, Mortgage: 2827, Principal: 2209, Interest: 618},
{Date: "Jun 2020 ( NaN )", Balance: 736760, Mortgage: 2827, Principal: 2211, Interest: 616}]

// To get the last 3 elements.
console.log(monthyInfo.slice(-3))
```

Comment: Thank you so much for your help this works well, I really appreciate it.

Answer (score 1):

```
let arr = new Array();
monthlyInfo.map((info,index)=>{
while(index>monthlyInfo.length()-3){
arr.push(info);
}
})
```

or just use Array.slice() function